# What is the concept of soul in islam

Tags: quran, soul, knowing-islam

Does soul exist inside our body, does soul has any gender, how can I find that I have a soul , what is the concept of soul in Islam.

Comment: humans have very limited knowledge about the soul, many things are still secret

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for my bad english.

Rooh is a large concept, like a container including several subtil organs.

We learn in the Quran that before coming in this mortal world, Allah grouped all human beings in the world of Roohs. (Quran, 7/172) He asked a question. We answered.

From this we understand :

Rooh is a name of an **organization** containing **faculties** like speaking without even without words, or hearing even without ears. From these subtil organs :

- the Rooh itself, an special organ within this organisation. It's role is to receive the light from God. Each human being is receiving divine light. The Quran says : **Know that God stands between man and his heart, and you shall all be gathered in His presence. (8/24)** This verse is not about mu'min only. It concerns each human being.
- Nafs :The faculty to desire ; we call it pejoratively Nafs or Ego. Some scholars explain thath Rooh is called Rooh when it is outside the body and Nafs when it's inside. But this explanation seems to be incorrect because lot of Hadiths say that death is the time where Rooh is extracting from the Body. It seems more appropriate to distinguish between the two.
- 'Aql : the faculty to analyse
- Qalb : the heart ; it's role is to reflect the light coming from the Rooh, and enlightning all other faculties, that's why his importance is crucial. The Messenger of Allah was asking again and again "O Allah, keep my heart firm to your obedience, dont deviate it"
- Memory : the faculty to remind and to forget
  ...

All these faculties constitute the Rooh as a container, and Rooh as the soul is also in this subtil organization.

For example : a person starts speaking but stops abruptly. His faculty of speaking even without words is so fast that it spoke in himself without activating his voice.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

According to my best knowledge

**1.** The soul exists inside your brain or in whole body but you can't find it it is intangible like it belongs to other dimension which humans can't reach.

**2.** It is ambiguous that soul have gender but there is two categories good soul and bad souls in Islam which are immortals but they must have to leave your body to become immortal.

**3.** The concept is of soul is that you your body just physical representation in this temporary world your soul will get rewarded or punished according to your virtues

**NOTE:remember i am not scholar this is just community contribution so might still need to refer to scholar.**

Answer (score 0):

And they ask you [O Muhammad] concerning the rooh [the spirit]. Say: ‘The rooh: it is one of the things, the knowledge of which is only with my Lord. And of knowledge, you (mankind) have been given only a little.’ [Quran, Surah al-Israa 17:85]”

Comment: This can hardly be regarded as an answer for the question: Evidences don't speak for themselves. See [answer].